# Still facing the problem in Orientation in iPhone

Tags: iphone

In my application I have 15 screens. In that I'm using `UIViewController` for all screens and in all screens I'm using the below way to call other screen:

```
AppDelegate *appRefre = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:appRefre.frmReferencesLink animated:YES];
```

And the below code is activated in all screen for orientation to control the user to switch from one orientation to other mode

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
          if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
           {
            return YES;
           }    
          else
          {
            return NO;
          }
}
```

But when i run my application in iPhone device my application gets terminated when i physically rotate my iphone device from `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` or `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`.

And One more things is that when my application launch I used following code for launching my application:

1) I made a pointer in mydelegate.h file:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Then synthesize its property

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

2) In mydelegat.m
 I Wrote

```
@synthesize navigationController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{
 navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:DefaultViewLink];    
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];


}
```

3) In above point DefaultView is launch first and gets remove from view and then actual my application come into picture.

So I want my application to be in portrait mode for all screens I don't want my application will switch to other mode.It remains the same as in portrait mode after rotation to any other mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow your application to be viewed in landscape mode, then don't implement any of the rotation functionality. There is obviously a bug in your code somewhere but (I suspect that you must have implemented code to respond to the rotation events) but if you don't need to be able to rotate the device then just remove this code.

Answer (score 0):

Like s1mm0t says, there must be a bug somewhere else in your code which is causing the app to crash. Run your app with "Build and Debug" when the device is connected to your computer. When it crashes you can then view the call stack and find the code that caused the crash.